# Mount NTFS HDD on linux

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, automount

I have an external HDD, Maxtor, with an NTFS partition on it.  How can this be mounted on an RHEL5 OS?

Answer (score 5):

assuming you have ntfs-3g installed, you can mount it by using

```
mount /dev/sdX# -t ntfs-3g /media/MOUNTPOINT
```

WHERE:

```
X = letter (depends on your computer)
# = number (partition number you want to mount)
MOUNTPOINT = folder (where this disk would be mounted)
```

Comment: use a command like `fdisk -l` to get a list of possible device names.

Comment: Is ntfs3g read-writable now? Last I heard it was still RO and RW is experimental. To be safe you can mount the volume as read only by modifying the above command as:

mount /dev/sdX# -t ntfs-3g -o ro /media/MOUNTPOINT