# How to mount an NTFS drive on a Linux VM on Google Compute Engine

Tags: linux, mount, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ntfs

Some of my data is on a drive that a Windows VM used, but I'd rather continue my work under a flavor of Linux. What is the foolproof way to mount this drive if it was formatted with an NTFS file system?

Here is an old [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/155427/196930) suggesting `ntfs-3g` for this but with an unresolved question in a comment, which makes me hesitant to play around without any risk of data loss.

(I guess there is no other way to get the data onto a disk that is more easily mounted by Linux flavors of GCE, and of course, I cannot reformat the drive keeping the data intact. Or if I can, let me know in a comment and I can ask a separate question for that answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of how accurate an answer might be is highly recommended to try any suggestion /or recommendations outside of your production environment to avoid any potential data loss or downtime. i.e. using a temp dev VM to test the suggestion prior to implementing them.

Since you are already on GCP, you can [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) of the instance, [create a dev instance from the snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot), and you are good to start testing.

With regards to mounting the NTFS disk, you can create a file system as noted in the [following document](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mkpart.html)

`$ mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX2`

Creates a new partition, without creating a new file system on that partition.

`Command: mkpart [part-type fs-type name] start end`

Similar question has been answered in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261515/how-can-i-mount-a-disk-without-formatting-it).